# add value of another variable to variable in loop

Tags: stata

I'd like to do something like that

```
gen var1 = 0
gen var2 = 0

forval x = 1/5 {
replace var1 = `x'
replace var2 = var2 + var1
}
```

Namely I want to replace *var2* by its old value plus *var1*. In a programming language like Python this works but in Stata it doesn't. 
My goal is not to create a lot of variables! That's why I want to update the variable *var2* in every cycle of the loop. I my loop would run from 1 to 100, I don't want to create 100 variables in order to get a nice solution.

In my example, in the first cycle of the loop, *var1* becomes 1 and *var2* also becomes 1. In the second cycle *var1* should be 2 and *var2* should become 3 since it adds the old value of *var2* (which is 1) to the new value of *var1* which is 2. In the third cylce *var1* should become 3 and *var2* should become 3 + 3 which is the old value of *var2* plus the value of *var1* in this cyle. So on and so forth. That's what I want to have!

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate more on your question. What I understand is that you want the sum of two variables which can be achieved simply with `gen var3 = var1 + var2` (as to not modify with a `replace` your original variable). What do you intend with the loop?

Comment: +1. This question is obscure. It's not clear whether you want to work on variable names as well as just as sum their values across observations.

Comment: Sorry for being unprecise. I now edited my question. Hopefully you can help me now.

Comment: please post all the loop code

Comment: You've accepted @Maarten Buis's answer, so the implication is that you got something from it, and that's good. As a resource for other users visiting the site, this question remains of very little value without clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for a loop:

```
clear all
set obs 100
gen id = _n
tsset id

gen var1 = _n - 1
gen var2 = 0
replace var2 = l.var2 + l.var1 if _n > 1
```

If you just want to know the "end-result", i.e. the values for var1 and var2 at the end of the loop, then you can use Mata:

```
mata
a = 0
b = 0
for (i = 1 ; i <= 100; i++) {
    a = i
    b = b + a
}
a
b
end
```